# is it possible to combine 2 differents styles in Matplotlib or seaborn in one plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, mplfinance

I don't know if it's possible  with Matplotlib or seaborn or another tools to plot 1 line and 1 bar (candlestick style)  , both in one figure . Like the image below (in excel) :

The x-axis and y-axis are the same

[image]

following the response below , I choose mplfinance  : [mplfinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance)

i have the following dataframe (daily)

[image]
and with the following function we can plot :

```
def ploting_chart(daily):
    # Take marketcolors from 'yahoo'
    mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(base_mpf_style='yahoo',up='#ff3300',down='#009900',inherit=True)

    # Create a style based on `seaborn` using those market colors:
    s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style='seaborn',marketcolors=mc,y_on_right=True,
    gridstyle = 'solid' , mavcolors = ['#4d79ff','#d24dff']
    )

    # **kwargs
    kwargs = dict(
        type='candle',mav=(7,15),volume=True, figratio=(11,8),figscale=2,
        title = 'Covid-19 Madagascar en traitement',ylabel = 'Total en traitement',
        update_width_config=dict(candle_linewidth=0.5,candle_width=0.5),
        ylabel_lower = 'Total'
        )

    # Plot my new custom mpf style:
    mpf.plot(daily,**kwargs,style=s,scale_width_adjustment=dict(volume=0.4))
```

I get the final result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `plt.figure` or `plt.subplots` gives you a figure object and then you can plot as many figures as you want. In fact if you use

```
import seaborn as sns
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,7)) # make a subplot of 1 row and 1 column


g1 = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri,ax=ax) # ax=axis object is must
g2 = sns.some_other_chart(your_data, ax=ax)
g3 = ax.some_matlotlib_chart(your_data) # no need to use ax=ax
```

`Seaborn` does not support `Candlestick` but you can plot using the `matplotlib` on the same axis.

```
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
candlestick_ohlc(ax, data.values, width=0.6, colorup='g', colordown='r') # just a dummy code to explain. YOu can see the ax object here as first arg
```

You can even use the pandas `df.plot(data,kind='bar',ax=ax,**kwargs)` to plot within the same axis object.

**Note**: Some of the `seaborn` charts do not support plotting on the same `ax` because they use their own `grid` such as `relplot`

Comment: Pleasure. Repaying the debt one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [**mplfinance**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials) allows you to plot multiple data sets, on the same plot, or on multiple subplots, where each one can be any of candlestick, ohlc-bars, line, scatter, or bar chart.

For more information, see for example:

- **[Adding Your Own Technical Studies to Plots](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb)**
- **[Subplots: Multiple Plots on a Single Figure](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md)**, including:

  - [The Panels Method](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb)
  - [External Axes Method](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb)

Note, as a general rule, it is recommended to ***not*** use the "[External Axes Method](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb)" if what you are trying to accomplish ***can*** be done otherwise with mplfinance in panels mode.